# Editing multiple .htaccess files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo

We got around 500 websites on our server and all of them has their own user directory.

```
/home/siteA/public_html/
/home/siteB/public_html/
/home/siteC/public_html/
```

All of them has its own .htaccess file and its duplicated.

What i wanna do is comment out last row of each file. is it possible to do it without actually editing all files by hand.

Comment: In its current form, this belongs on Superuser.com as it is not a programming question, and you need to specify what platform you are on so people can recommend shell scripts or tools. But maybe it is worth using the chance and finding out whether you might be able to condense all those htaccesses into one central one? Seeing as they seem to contain more or less the same things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Assuming you have a list of which directories are sites in say `sites.txt`, just loop over them like this:

```
while read sitename; do 
    sed -ri "$ s/(.+)/#\1/" /home/$sitename/.htaccess
done < sites.txt
```

Just make sure that you don't have a bunch of empty lines at the end of your files; this will comment out the *last* line, not the last line with content. If you need to do that, it will become much more difficult.